# Which Vagrant distrib should I use for Ubuntu 11.10 x32

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I have ubuntu 11.10 x32 version on my PC, and need to set up a Vagrant for a project, but couldnt find a distrib on their download page:

http://downloads.vagrantup.com/tags/v1.0.3 (current)

Both vagrant_1.0.3_i686.deb and vagrant_1.0.3_x86_64.deb obviously doesn't work. How could I obtain and run version for my OS?

Comment: Why exactly does vagrant_1.0.3_i686.deb "obviously" not work?

Comment: @Gerry - because it isn't for i386, maybe? At least, Ubuntu's package manager thinks it is not compliant.

Comment: I'm guessing the packagers just assigned the wrong file name. Perhaps they are not familiar with Debian's concept of architectures. Try simply renaming it to `_i386`.

Comment: Already worked it around by simply installing it as a ruby gem, not an issue as I play around with ruby every now and than. Anyway thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant is a ruby Gem, so you always could run latest version under any platform if you could run Ruby. Of course you should install OpenBox and maybe tweak some settings that are setted up by standalone installer, but this way it is at least work.